# While converting from tuple to list ,I got an error

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\MY WORKS\Python\list operations.py", line 23, in <module>
    new = list(tuple)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: please add more information to the question.

Comment: tuple = (123,'Deepak','Mithun','Boo');
new = list(tuple)
print "\nList elements:\n\n",new

Comment: `tuple` is a builtin type. By using your own `tuple` variable, you've masked the real one. The same goes for `list`. From your error code, I think You've assigned `list = "somestring"` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Ya...Now I m fixed it..thanks for your support..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have likely overridden the builtin `list` with a string. Look for something like this in your code:

```
list = "some_string"
```

You would then get that error for trying to "call" `some_string`, as the built-in `list` function is no longer available.